# Steam API giving empty JSON

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

I have been having trouble with the Steam API. When I run the query:

[https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key="mykey"&steamid="aSteamID"](https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=%22mykey%22&steamid=%22aSteamID%22)

I get:

{"response":{}}

Sometimes the query works fine and gives the info I am looking for. I am not sure why this inconsistency occurs.

I have tried looking for other options such as: trying a different query, http instead of https, and looking through steam API documentation. None of these have worked.

UPDATE: I solved this by getting a new steam API key. Still unsure about why the old one was having trouble so I will leave this up.